# Are "*_squash" (all_squash/no_all_squash, root_squash/no_root_squash, anon_uid/anon_gid) options in NFSv4 still rellevant?

Tags: nfs4, mapping

Nowadays NFSv4 uses /etc/idmapd.conf to do the mapping of usernames between server and client machines. So I don't get the point of having these "*_squash" options, which seems very "NFSv3-flavoured" and redundant, if I'm not wrong.

There's any reason for keeping using these options in a NFSv4 shared folder?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As the end result of mapping through `idmapd` you get uid/gid(s), this all options are still valid.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. But...are you sure of this? I think the mapping is done by the "Nobody-User"/"Nobody-Group" and "Method" lines in idmapd.conf file. If last one has the value "nsswitch" (the default one), I understand the mapping is done via nsswitch.conf file, which normally points to /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files. So here the UID/GID would be irrellevant. What's the point I'm missing? Thanks!!